# Remove row of a CSV file based on the index by iterating over the rows

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file, and I want to remove a row at a particular index.

```
CSV.foreach(@filepath, @csv_options) do |row|
    # delete row if row's index == n 
end
```

I found alternative solutions by storing the CSV file in a `@file` variable and by doing `@file.delete_at(n)` but it won't actually delete it from the CSV file. I thought of erasing the CSV file and copying what's stored in `@file` but that seems way too complicated.

Is there a way to do it directly from the CSF file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you thought of is not complicated, just rewrite the file.

```
File.open(@filepath, 'w') { |f| f.puts(@file) }
```